# Query RabbitMQ status real-time

Tags: rabbitmq

**Is there a way to query RabbitMQ message counts real-time/quickly?**

We have a scenario where we need to query the status of RabbitMQ message queues real-time, but the REST APIs available from the web management plugin appear to have a delay of several seconds before they return updated info, and the tool that powers them (rabbitmqctl) seems to be very slow (several seconds to return from rabbitmqctl list_queues).

The REST API responds very quickly and seems ideal for our task, but as I mentioned, it returns "stale data" for several seconds -- some kind of caching at some level, not in our code/layer.

We have tests that publish messages, then wait for the messages to be processed before checking results.  The results can be many different things (SQL inserts, files written, data added to proprietary systems, etc).  The common item between all tests are messages, so it seems ideal to wait here, instead of creating waits on each specific area -- and that doesn't work at all when the expected results are "no data was written (message was ignored)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these plugins for publishing/consuming RabbitMQ queues

https://github.com/jlavallee/JMeter-Rabbit-AMQP

http://indikasampath.blogspot.it/2015/08/jmeter-publisher-subscriber-for.html

Comment: We use a .NET client (don't have the link handy but it's the official one linked on the RabbitMQ page) for consuming and publishing.  I don't see how we can use that to gets stats on queues that we don't want to consume (our test code can't consume them, that would invalidate our tests).  We could setup routing to get a duplicate of every message in a queue that our test uses, which would let us know when a message was published, but what we really need to know is when a message is consumed (by the code we are testing, not our test code).

Comment: http://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/api/RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html  is what we use, just noticed MessageCount -- could be a way we can get a count, as long as this is super fast and accurate, unlike the REST API

Comment: AFAIK you can't assert whether a message is consumed; you can only listen to the same queue and assume someone else is consuming.
Anyway, these plugins allow to connect to the bus so they should be as fast as any RMQ library, obviously faster than APIs which -in add- use higher levels of the network stack.

Comment: Thanks, this works for us.  I was hoping there was a way to get the REST API to be real-time but I believe it uses statsd behind the scenes and therefor has a built-in delay since it is pulling from aggregate data on another system instead of directly from the queues.